# PHP Form is Updating SQL Table Even When SQL Table Column Isn't Blank

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a PHP form that will only allow the user to update the MySQL Table column `photo`, if the `photo` column is blank. Currently, the form will still update the `photo` column even if there is data other than "blank" data. For example, the `photo` column contains the data "columbia.jpg" and the user submits the form with the image "Jefferson.jpg" in the first input. The `image` column's data gets replaced from `columbia.jpg` to `jefferson.jpg` when it is not supposed to replace it at all. Instead it should return an error message stating that the user must first delete the old image before adding a new one. The column data should only get replaced when the column data is equal to "blank". (Not the word "blank" but "".)

Here is my full PHP page code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $sn = (int)($_GET["id"]);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>MySQL file upload example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Photo 1: <input type="file" name="photo"><br>
        <input name="add_image" id="add_image" type="submit" value="Upload file">
    </form>
    <p>
        <a href="pdfget.php">See all files</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['add_image']))
{
$dbLink = new mysqli('daom', 'sm', 'aer', 'kabm');

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

$query = "SELECT photo FROM used_trailers WHERE id = $sn";
$result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $query);
$array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if($query = " "){
//Writes the information to the database 
        $query1 = 
            "UPDATE used_trailers ".
       "SET photo = '$pic' ".
       "WHERE id = $sn" ;
        // Execute the query
        $results = $dbLink->query($query1);

        // Check if it was successfull
        if($results) {
            echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
               . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded to Photo 1, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 }
} else {
echo '<p>You must first delete the "Photo 1" image, $array, in order to add a new photo. This is to prevent the server from overloading with too many images.</p>';
}
}
}
               echo "$query1";
?>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Sidenote: Are you sure you have your bracing done correctly? I.e.: `if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $sn = (int)($_GET["id"]);` it's closing at the end of your code without anything in between to make it come in and out of PHP.

Comment: Regardless of bracing, the code is functioning as purposed.

Comment: Ok. I thought it might have had something to do with it. Glad you found your solution below.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, though. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome Michael, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your script. First of all `if ($query = " ")` will always return true, because you are assigning the variable `$query` the string `" "`. To correctly check this, you'd need to use `if ($query == " ")`.

However, this won't solve your problem as `$query` is the query - not the result. This should work

```
$query = "SELECT photo FROM used_trailers WHERE id = $sn";
$result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $query);
$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if (empty($array['photo'])){
    //etc.
}
```